# Bounds of the correlation between 2 random variables given their correlations with a third variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, covariance, correlation

Suppose we have corr(X,Y) = p1 and corr(Y,Z) = p2, how do we determine the range of possible values for corr(X,Z)?

Comment: Not to denigrate "kimchi lover" 's answer, but I think mine is better, so you might look at it. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $\rho=\operatorname{corr}(X,Z), p_1=\operatorname{corr}(X,Y), p_2=\operatorname{corr}(Y,Z) $, the matrix
$$M=\pmatrix{1&p_1&\rho\\p_1&1&p_2\\\rho&p_2&1}$$
must be positive semidefinite, and conversely, if $M$ is psd, there exist random variables $X,Y,Z$ for which $M$ is the correlation matrix.  So your answer is:
for given $p_1,p_2$, the set of possible correlation coefficiets $\rho$ is the set of numbers that make $M$ psd.

Comment: This is for independent random variables, I think.

Comment: Thank you! So in practice what would be the best way to check this? Use the fact that the determinant must be between 0 and 1?

Comment: @RiversMcForge Why do you think that?  If  you are right, why is there a $p_1$ and a $p_2$ in the problem statement?

Comment: @KeithWynroe I won't answer your question directly, but: there is some famous property of positive definite matrices that almost gives you everything you need.  Assume first that $|p_1|<1$.

Comment: @kimchilover I constructed examples of random variables $X, Y, Z$ so that $\operatorname{corr}(X, Y) = p_1$, $\operatorname{corr}(Y, Z) = p_2$, and  $\operatorname{corr}(X, Z)$ is arbitrary. In my example, $X, Y, Z$ are not independent, but I think you're right if the variables have to be independent, although OP didn't specify independence in his question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any restrictions on what $\operatorname{corr}(X, Z)$ could be, without further information. For any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, let $A, B$ be two random variables which are uncorrelated with $Y$ and for which $\operatorname{corr}(A, B) = c$.

Then taking $X = A + p_1 Y/\operatorname{Var}(Y)$, $Z = B + p_2 Y/\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ gives:

- $\operatorname{corr}(X, Y) = p_1$
- $\operatorname{corr}(Y, Z) = p_2$
- $\operatorname{corr}(X, Z) = c + \frac{p_1 p_2}{\operatorname{Var}(Y)},$

and since $c$ was arbitrary, so is $\operatorname{corr}(X, Z)$.

Comment: To take an extreme example if corr(X,Y) = corr(Y,Z) = 1 then corr(Y,Z) can’t be anything other than 1 too? More generally it seems like we can usually restrict the third pairwise correlation at least a bit unless corr(X,Y) = corr(Y,Z) = 0?

Comment: Maybe if the variables are independent, but if we don't assume $X, Y, Z$ are independent, my example works to show $\operatorname{corr}(X, Z)$ can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

The covariance is
$$
\operatorname E((X-\operatorname EX)(Y-\operatorname EY)).
$$
This satisfies the definition of an inner product on the vector space of random variables with finite variance. And the inner product of two vectors is the product of the norms times the cosine of the angle between them. Thus the cosine is
$$
\frac{\operatorname E((X-\operatorname EX)(Y-\operatorname EY))}{\operatorname{sd}(X)\operatorname{sd}(Y)}
$$
i.e. it is the correlation.

So suppose $\theta_1= \arccos(\operatorname{corr}(X,Y))$ and $\theta_2 = \arccos(\operatorname{corr}(Y,Z)).$ If the angle between $X$ and $Y$ is $\theta_1$ and that between $Y$ and $Z$ is $\theta_2$ then the angle between $X$ and $Z$ cannot exceed $\theta_1+\theta_2,$ so
$$
\operatorname{corr}(X,Z) \le \cos(\theta_1+\theta_2).
$$